# Struct Field undeclared in main

Tags: c, struct, malloc, scanf

Hey all, I'm writing a C program, and I want to have an array of structs malloc'd up and filled with data from a file. Here's my typedef for the struct:

```
typedef struct {
   char name[5];
   int age;
} person;
```

And then in my main function I do this:

```
  person *A ;
  int  i ;
  FILE * fin;

  fin = fopen( "people", "r" );

  A = ( person * ) malloc( sizeof(person) * 10 );
  if ( A == NULL ) { printf( "Error mallocing \n" ) ; return -1 ; }

  for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {

    fscanf( fin, "%s %d", name->A[i], age->A[i] );

  }
```

Now unfortunately when I try to compile I get the error that name and age are undeclared in main. I've never tried using fscanf to make structs before, but I'm at a bit of a loss here. Thanks in advance to anyone who knows anything!

Comment: If you are going to hard-code the number of structures you are `malloc`-ing, why not declare them statically?

Comment: Its just placeholder code, I'm not really going to hard code the number in

Comment: @bta Perhaps it's just an example or trial and the count will be variable in the final code.

Comment: The answer is already posted, but when I saw "name->A[i]", I must admit, I thought it was funny. Good show.

Comment: @Daniel For some reason the first thing it reminded me of was the lovely `5[A]` way of indexing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just accidentally got your syntax backwards (that and the fact that indexing the pointer returns an actual struct, not a pointer to it so the pointer to member operator `->` is not needed): `A[i].name` and `&(A[i].age)`. Also checking the return value from `fopen` might be a good idea.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you very much, and everyone else who helped as well.